# Filtering dataframe row values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
County  Town    Area    Road    Fuel Type   Station Date listed
0   Uasin Gishu Eldoret  None   None      Both Super & Diesel   Total   April 20, 2022, 1:07 a.m.
1   Nairobi    Nairobi  None    None      Diesel    National Oil    April 19, 2022, 1:44 p.m. 
petrol_data[(petrol_data['Area']=='None')&(petrol_data['Town']=='Eldoret')]
```

Returns`County  Town    Area    Road    Fuel Type   Station Date listed`

Returns empty while there's data with None value how can I filter and get to show None values?

Comment: Welcome to SO - Noticed your efforts to format the code - little tip, provide your dataframe in such a way that it can be easily reproduced for example `petrol_data.head().to_dict()` to create and with `print(petrol_data.head().to_markdown())` to show output.

Comment: `None` and `'None'` are not the same in Python. Are you sure your Area column has strings rather than null values?

Answer (score 0):

If your data is:

```
import pandas as pd
petrol_data = pd.DataFrame(
[[0, "Uasin Gishu", "Eldoret", None, None, "Both Super & Diesel   Total", "April 20, 2022, 1:07 a.m."],\
[1, "Nairobi", "Nairobi", None, None, "Diesel National Oil", "April 19, 2022, 1:44 p.m."]], columns=["id", "County", "Town", "Area", "Road", "Fuel Type", "Station Date listed"])
```

You may get your desired output with:

```
petrol_data[(petrol_data['Area'].isna())&(petrol_data['Town']=='Eldoret')]
```

As the output is:

```
   id       County  ...                    Fuel Type        Station Date listed
0   0  Uasin Gishu  ...  Both Super & Diesel   Total  April 20, 2022, 1:07 a.m.

[1 rows x 7 columns]
```

The right way is to use the `isna()`method to check if the rows are `None` or not.